# Regarding immutable class complete functionality

Tags: java, immutability

I was developing an immutable class . below is my immutable class , please advise me it is completely immutable or if I am missing something or its immutablity can be broken down by anyhow then please advise..

```
public final class ImmutableReminder{
    private final Date remindingDate;

    public ImmutableReminder (Date remindingDate) {
        if(remindingDate.getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not set reminder” +
                        “ for past time: " + remindingDate);
        }
        this.remindingDate = new Date(remindingDate.getTime());
    }

    public Date getRemindingDate() {
        return (Date) remindingDate.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: from my view, it's OK:) but don't forget to check for null

Comment: The constructor already checks for `null` ... implicitly :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a copy of remindingDate.getTime() BEFORE checking it against your class invariants. Otherwise an attacker with a reference to your remindingDate could call a .set method on it to change the value after you've checked it's validity.

long time = remindingDate.getTime();

```
public final class ImmutableReminder{
    private final Date remindingDate;

    public ImmutableReminder (Date remindingDate) {
        long incomingTime = remindingDate.getTime()

        if(incomingTime < System.currentTimeMillis()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not set reminder” +
                        “ for past time: " + remindingDate);
        }
        this.remindingDate = new Date(incomingTime);
    }

    public Date getRemindingDate() {
        return (Date) remindingDate.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I read about it in [Effective Java 2nd edition](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683) A good read

Answer (score 0):

This class is what you normally call immutable.
However you said "or its immutablity can be broken down by anyhow"....in java, reflection can breaks all rules. Some really evil person could detect your private final remindingDate, and change it, making it accessible first and then call setters on it.
You may use a better Date implementation, like joda time DateTime which is itself immutable...but someone could even make the field non final using reflection.
So this class **is** immutable, but it is **not unbreakable**.
And there is no way around it.

Answer (score -1):

If it's the class in its entirety, it is indeed immutable.